# Wordpress plugin recommendation (fancybox/on-click popup with image slider, text, and button capabilities)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, popup, fancybox, lightbox

Can anyone recommend a Wordpress plugin that has the capability to give me what you see in this example image. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivyuy.jpg)

Or give me some ideas for keywords I can search?

I've looking into Lightboxes, Fancyboxes, Pop-ups, and none have all the features you see here, with the image slider, information, ability to add a button, etc. Thanks!